# What does pointer array from malloc mean?

Tags: c

```
unsigned char *dup = malloc(size);
```

My question may be naive. What does `dup[2]` mean? Is it a pointer to the third char from the malloced memory or it's the value of the third char from the malloced memory? I have searched google but found no result to explain this. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: It should be easy to find this on google though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's the value of the third char from the malloced memory?

This.

`dup[2]` equivalent to `*(dup + 2)`. The `+ 2` implicitly acts like `+ 2 * sizeof(char)`.

If you want a pointer to the third char in the memory, without dereferencing it, then you just use the same as above. without the dereferencing operator:

```
unsigned char *thirdChar = dup + 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

`dup[2]` is sematically identical to `*(dup + 2)`. So it is the value of the third byte pointed to by `dup`. That is, the memory addresses are:

```
dup, dup+1, dup+2, ....., dup+size-1
```

Note that `malloc` does not initialize the returned memory, so strictly speaking, the value of `dup[2]` could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, `dup[k]` in this case representing the third character of the string, which is very much similiar to `*(dup + 2)`.

The supporting code as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {

unsigned char *dup = malloc(10);
scanf("%s", dup);
printf("%c", dup[2]);
printf("\n%c", *(dup+2));
   return 0;
}
```

The output being the same for both `printf` statement, it made it very clear.